# A synonym for "don't omit" not including a negativiser

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, antonyms, double-negation

I have a technical document with a lot of sentences like "Use X." or "Don't use Y."

Instead of "Don't use ..." I sometimes use "Omit ...". Whether to choose the former form or the latter depends on whether "bad thing" could be "removed" without any additional changes.

> #### Parentheses to make operator precedence explicit
>
> Omit them.
>
> ```
> (2 * 3) - 1   // Wrong
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 * 3 - 1     // Correct
> ```

> #### Else and Else If after jump statements
>
> Don't use them.
>
> ```
> // Wrong
> if (a = b)
>   return x
> else if (a = c)
>   return y
> else
>   return z
> ```
>
> ```
> // Correct
> if (a = b)
>   return x
> if (a = c)
>   return y
> return z
> ```

But sometimes I need to say "Don't omit ..." and such a wording is somewhat very close to a double negative. Since the document discourages double negatives in code, it's not a good idea to have them in the document itself.

Comment: 'Include'? '... are mandatory'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Include" looks good to me where is used to describe parentheses or other punctuation marks. I'm not sure it looks good to me where is used for something bigger. _"`RETURN` after the auto-execute section. Don't omit it."_ vs. _"`RETURN` after the auto-execute section. Include it."_ The second version looks worse to me. (I'm not a native speaker, though...)

Comment: @jsv The problem in the case of "something bigger" is that you're treating *omit* as a synonym of both **exclude** (for small items), and **forget** (for large items). It's highly unlikely you'll find any single word you can negate that can include both of those senses in context.

Comment: @jsv You can look at a thesaurus to see if any [antonym of omit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/omit) is appropriate.